# Must delete cache in Chrome to see css changes I made on a Wordpress wesbite. Can this be handled automatic?

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome, caching, wordpress-theming

I've made an Wordpress theme. But recently, after every change I make in the code, the cache in Chrome has to be deleted to see the change.

Can this be handled automatic with a plugin or a line of code to add to the funtions.php?

Comment: have you just tried doing a hard refresh? (ctrl + f5)  Usually that forces browsers to redownload all files

Comment: Wow that works! Thanks Pete!

Comment: you're welcome, glad I could help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling Chrome cache for website development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make the link to the css use a query string with a timestamp. This way you will get a unique link each load.

Assuming you are using wp_enque_style() to load the style, there is a version parameter, set this to the current time with the function time() and it will add it to the link.

```
function themeslug_enqueue_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'mystyle', 'path/to/mystyle.css', false, time() ); 
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'themeslug_enqueue_style' );
```

[More info about wp_enqueue_scripts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts)

Comment: You would have to remember not to put this into production otherwise you will cause everyone to redownload files all the time -not great for page load times